# is it ok for async and defer syntax to be async="async"?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have DNN with skins. my head tag has runat="server" so I tried adding a tag inside the head tags as so

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%#GoogleAPIkey%>"></script>
```

in the code behind I set the var GoogleAPIkey in a property.
the issue is it does not load the value.

I then tried adding the script tag in code behind as this

```
    HtmlGenericControl jqueryInclude = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    jqueryInclude.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
    jqueryInclude.Attributes.Add("async", "async");
    jqueryInclude.Attributes.Add("defer", "defer");
    jqueryInclude.Attributes.Add("src", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + GoogleAPIkey );
```

this method outputs the tag as

```
<script async="async" defer="defer" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx"></script>
```

is this valid syntax or do I need to persue a different method of writing it out - or perhaps even moving it out of the head tags.

Answer (score 4):

The spec states that [`async` is a boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async). As for how [boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) are specified:

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or [...] the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> **Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

So technically, what matters is that the attribute exists, not what it's value is. This means you could use `async="async"`.

Comment: I believe, not 100% sure though, that XHTML required attributes to always have a value, which means you would need to use `async=async` in order to satisfy that validator. In any case, it won't hurt 'normal' HTML validators/browsers, since they will just ignore the value and work based on the fact the attribute exists (as Mike C pointed out)